# Phase difference for a central maxima in diffraction

Tags: visible-light, interference, diffraction

[image: Central Maximum for Diffraction]

For a central maximum in diffraction, contributions from all the parts of slits like point C and D are supposed to be in phase. I am not getting why contributions from all parts of slits should in phase. I think phase difference will depend on path difference and looks like there will be path difference between different parts of slit like CD and AB will have path difference as I show in picture.

Comment: C and D would have a different path than A. You don’t even need to use all parts of the slit for this to happen. Just calculate from the two edges of the slit.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that there will be a path difference comparing AB and CB.  When we assume that all the waves arrive at B in phase we are using the far field approximation.  Diffraction analyzed this way is referred to as [Fraunhofer diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction). This does not hold if point B is near the aperture, in that case you need to use the more complicated [Fresnel diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_diffraction) equation.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the contributions from different parts of the slit will be rigorously out of phase. However, at long distance $L$ from the slit, you can show that the path length different between two points $A$ and $C$ can be written $\delta_{A,C} = n \overrightarrow{AC} \cdot \overrightarrow{u}_{AC, B}$, where $\overrightarrow{u}_{AC, B}$ is the unit vector from the middle of $[AC]$ pointing towards $B$. But at very large distances, if you look around the center of the screen, $\overrightarrow{u}$ is basically horizontal, while $\overrightarrow{AC}$ is vertical, meaning that their dot product is $0$.

The next contribution is second order, which is neglected here (true if $a^2/L << \lambda$, where $a$ is the size of the slit). For instance, for a quite large $1\,\mathrm{mm}$ slit, and $\lambda$ in the visible range, the LHS will be smaller than the RHS for $L >> 1\,\mathrm{mm}$ (this is the criteria for being in the "far-field" approximation).

As you can see in the image below, constructive interferences at the center of the x axis do not occur for $\frac{L \lambda}{a^2} \lessapprox 1$ (near-field), but do occur for larger distances.

[image: Diffraction from a 1D slit]